# Get remote servers environment variables

Tags: windows, vbscript, environment-variables

**The problem:** We have Cobol applications that run from many servers (mostly server 2003) on our network. Many if not all of these applications use environment variables for there setting.

**The Question:** From one workstation can you gather the full list of environment variables from a list of known servers remote? Optimally i would like to do this in Batch, VBS, or the Powershell.

**The Answer:** In VBS

```
GetEnvironment("[RemoteServersName]")

Function GetEnvironment(ServerName)

    strComputer = ServerName
    Set objSWbemLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
    Set objSWbemServices = objSWbemLocator.ConnectServer _
        (strComputer, "root\cimv2", "[ValidLogonName]", "[PasswordForLogonName]")
    objSWbemServices.Security_.ImpersonationLevel = 3
    Set colVar = objSWbemServices.ExecQuery( _
        "Select * from Win32_Environment")
    For Each objVar in colVar
            WScript.StdOut.Write("Server Name: " & ServerName & VBNewLine)
            WScript.StdOut.Write("Description: " & objVar.Description & VBNewLine)
            WScript.StdOut.Write("Name: " & objVar.Name & VBNewLine)
            WScript.StdOut.Write("System Variable: " & objVar.SystemVariable & VBNewLine)
            WScript.StdOut.Write("User Name: " & objVar.UserName & VBNewLine)
            WScript.StdOut.Write("Variable Value: " & objVar.VariableValue & VBNewLine & VBNewLine)
    Next

End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have not tried it, but you can check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394143%28VS.85%29.aspx) out. the examples is vbscript, change strComputer to the IP address of your remote and see how it goes. For many remote hosts, use a for loop.

Comment: Had to use this page as well http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389290(VS.85).aspx but thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Here is the powershell command:

```
gwmi win32_environment -computername dc1.acme.com
```

And if you want a condensed version:

```
gwmi win32_environment -computername dc1.acme.com |select name,variablevalue |ft -auto
```