# Remote Windows Computer OS Root Drive Letter

Tags: windows, powershell, networking, command-prompt

How can I find the letter of `os` root drive ( for example C or D, etc...) on  Remote computer with windows Operating system by windows command prompt or power shell commands.

In local pc the "**set systemroot**" command can get the windows root drive but I want this equivalent command for remote computer...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get remote servers environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071819/get-remote-servers-environment-variables)

Answer (score 1):

Query WMI, Win32_OperatingSystem Class;

OS drive letter

```
Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName localhost -Property SystemDrive | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SystemDrive
```

or

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName localhost -Property SystemDrive | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SystemDrive
```

Windows directory

```
Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName localhost -Property WindowsDirectory | Select-Object -ExpandProperty WindowsDirectory
```

or

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName localhost -Property WindowsDirectory | Select-Object -ExpandProperty WindowsDirectory
```

Comment: thanks dude,
but it didnt work on windows 7.
i need it for run in php script in network for windows 7 clients